# Proper formulation of "contribute to" in subordinate sentence

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

I am writing a text about our project (say Project A), and I want to say that something which I am talking about (the three dots below), was motivated by requirements of project X, which I didn't talk about before. I want to say that our project A contributed the data to project X and the requirements of project X were a motivation for something I am talking before. I wanted to say it all simply in a subsentence (or subordinate clause or how do you call it). Could it be said like this? :

> ... It was also motivated by the requirements of Project X, to which the
> data from our project also contributed.

or like this? :

> ... It was also motivated by the requirements of Project X, where the
> data from our project also contributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those is quite right. Your project contributed its data; the data wasn’t a contributor. Try:

> *It was also motivated by the requirements of Project X, to which our project also contributed data.*

That is the more formal version of:

> *It was also motivated by the requirements of Project X, which our project also contributed data to.*

You could also simply say:

> *It was also motivated by the requirements of Project X, which used data from our project.*

(Without further context, I’m not certain the second *also* belongs in any of the above.)

Further reading: [Preposition placement in relative clauses](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/preposition-placement-relative-clauses/)

Comment: Thank you... I like the first two options. However, is "which" really appropriate here? Recently I learned that if the clause is defining, which this one is, one should use "that" rather than "which": https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/  Isn't it this case as well?

Comment: The clause is non-defining; it supplies additional information that can be left off without causing structural damage or a change in meaning to the sentence.

Comment: OK, thanks :-) Just curious, is English your native language?

Comment: Yes — American English.

Answer (score 0):

The first option you present is the standard usage.

> It was also motivated by the requirements of Project X, to which the data from our project also contributed.

Except there is a big problem—in this context, the pronoun "which" most probably refers back to *Project X*, and not *requirements*.

You also have your data contributing to the requirements. Data does not *contribute* to requirements—data *meets* (or *satisfies*, or what have you) requirements.

I'd add a noun after the comma.

> It was also motivated by the requirements of Project X, requirements which were satisfied by the data from our project.

Comment: no no, I don't want to refer to the requirements from the subclause! Just to the project X.